# Python3 Pandas whitespace in output file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, whitespace

I'm trying to write out the first column of a xlsx into a txt file for input to another tool. I have this code that works, but I can't seem to get rid of the spacing in front of every entry. Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys


df = pd.read_excel(sys.argv[1], sheet_name ='Sheet1', usecols="A", header=0)

my_file = open('hosts.txt','w')
for data in df.columns:
    # df[data].str.lstrip()
    my_file.write(df.replace(r'^\s*$', regex=True)[data].to_string(index=False)+'n')

my_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Read data with pandas
df = pd.read_excel('one_row.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols="A", header=0)

# method 1
# strip column A
df['A'] = df['A'].str.strip()
# Here you can use df.to_csv() to output to a txt file
df.to_csv('one_row.txt', sep='\t', index=False)



# method 2
data_list = df.iloc[:, 0].to_list()  # Convert to list
data_no_space_list = [i.strip() for i in data_list]    # strip space

data_str = '\n'.join(data_no_space_list)  # Use \n for newlines
with open('one_row2.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data_str)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Method 2 is what I chose to go with. I appreciate you taking the time to help out. Cheers

Comment: You're welcome. I'm a Chinese. This is the first time my answer has been adopted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't really provide any data I made a sample dataframe to copy from. This will iterate through your columns and get ride of the space in front of each column if it exists

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1' : [' A', ' B', 'C', ' D'],
    'Column2' : ['Word', ' Another Word', 'Third Word', ' Space Word']
})

for x in df.columns:
    df[x] = df[x].str.lstrip(' ')
```

Comment: Sorry for not adding input data. The input data is an excel spreadsheet that has a header in column A of discoverd_domain followed by dns names in the column.

Comment: I guess I would need to see y our data because when I run the code above even with multiple spaces before each field it comes back correctly

Comment: I do appreciate the help. An example excel file is here [link] (https://www.hopticalillusion.co/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/asset_conversion-1.xlsx)